# How to connect to Nodejs app on openshift by Tcp

Tags: node.js, openshift

Here is my Nodejs app which is running on Openshift.

```
var express = require('express');
var net = require('net');
var app = express();
var sock;

var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1'


//first of all connect to a stable client
console.log('waiting for connection\nfrom mobile server on port 5132');
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) { sock = socket; });
server.listen(5132,server_ip_address);// I want to connect to this server
// by a java socket


//receive request from other clients
app.get('/', function (req, res) 
{
    // retriving mobileNumber and message
    console.log('A new request\nreceived on 6544 ');
    var mobileNumber = req.query.mobileNumber;
    var message      = req.query.message;

    if (sock) 
    {
        sock.write(mobileNumber+"\n"+message+"\n");

    }

    res.end('i am ended');
});

app.listen(server_port,server_ip_address);
```

Here is my java client:
     socket = new Socket("ip address of server",5132);

It worked great on localhost but when I deployed it on Openshift.
I dont know how to connect to the server.listen(5132,server_ip_address);

Is there any other way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Only the following ports are exposed publicly for your applications on OpenShift Online 80(http),443(https),8000(ws),8443(wss).  Only the http/websocket protocols are available as all requests are routed through an apache proxy (for http), or a nodejs proxy (for websockets).  So you will not be able to make a raw tcp connection to your application on OpenShift Online.

You can review this page of the Developer Portal for more information about how connections are routed to your application: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html